# switching between multiple keyboard layouts

Tags: keyboard

Is there an easy way to set up multiple languages (my case english & hebrew) on Raspbian that can be switched using Alt-shift (or alike) ?

I tried to follow several threads (like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/multiple-keyboard-and-input-languages)) with no success so far.

Thanks

Comment: This is identical to the question you linked, which certainly *seems* to have a working answer (still apparently working as of [8 days ago](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=139608)). Can you update your question with some details of exactly what you tried, and what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to deal with the same issue, with limited success (switching between English (US) and Greek).

Adding in the terminal:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,gr
```

works for me. For you logically it should be:

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,il
```

Be careful, there can be no space between the comma and the second country code.

Only problem is that it resets after reboot. Adding to `/etc/default/keyboard` and altering `.bashrc` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of is Menu -> Preferences -> Mouse and Keyboard Settings.
Then the Keyboard tab and then Keyboard layout.

Although every time you restart the RPi it resets which is a nuisance I have not figured out how to get around yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to this. I am switching between English (GB) and Russian (phonetic).

This is from noobish-nix's blog:

https://noobish-nix.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-add-and-switch-keyboard-layout.html

I'm using Raspbian Buster.

Just open the configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

(Here I'm using nano, but feel free to use any other editor you please.)

Then add a line to the end of the file, beginning with an '@':

```
@setxkbmap -layout "gb,ru" -variant ",phonetic" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

for example. This should persist between reboots.

For switching between English (US) and Hebrew:

```
@setxkbmap -layout "us,il" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```