# How to use two keyboard layouts in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian-stretch, keyboard, pi-3b+

I am using Raspbian 9 (Stretch) and I want to use both English and Persian keyboard layouts at the same time.

Right now I have to go to the preferences every time I need a keyboard layout shift.

Is there a way to add a shortcut for this like windows' alt+shift or Mac's top menu icon?

Comment: I don't know if any answer here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/multiple-keyboard-and-input-languages may help - specifically [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5130/multiple-keyboard-and-input-languages)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/209597/how-do-i-change-keyboards-from-the-command-line#209598

Comment: @JaromandaX last part of the answer mention command line for X

Comment: well, that'll teach me for not reading the WHOLE answer :p

Comment: This fixed my issue: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57516/89768 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57516/89768

The link above fixed my issue.

Thanks to MaNyYaCk and Jaromanda X

Answer (score -1):

Right click on Taskbar >
add / remove panel items >
add >
keyboard layout Handler >
right click on keyboard layout Handler >
uncheck keep system layouts >
-Add >
Enjoy